# Plotting multiple graphs from one dataframe with a single x axis- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, plot, graph

I have searched every possible solution but it never seems to create the plots in a way that is legible for me. It should also work for potentially 100's of dataframe columns so a solution being in a loop or something of that nature would be preferred

My dataframe is roughly this

data=

```
Time    Pressure    Static Temperature    Stag Temperature
0       100         50                    75
10      105         55                    77
20      110         59                    81
30      106         57                    79
```

What I would like is 3 different graphs that plot Pressure, Static Temp, and Stag Temp vs Time which would be the X-axis.

My current code looks like

```
import pandas
data=pandas.read_csv(data.csv') 
for header in data:
    data.plot(x='System Time',y=header)
```

I think I understand the problem which is that for my data.plot needs to have y="Something in quotes" but I thought because header is a string it should work.

Any solution to get multiple graphs would be absolutely wonderful!

Also I apologize if my formatting is messed up as this is my first time posting!

Comment: Why would `x` would be `System Time`. Didn't you mean `Time` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
>>> data.plot(x="Time")
```

[image: The output plot]

However, to achieve this, I had to reformat your `data.csv` file to replace white spaces with commas, as it is the default separator in a **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues file. Maybe your original file is tabulated and in this case, your need to specify `sep='\t'` to the `read_csv()` call.

Comment: nicoco, This only gets me a single graph with every column's data if I don't use the for loop. If I include this within the loop, I get multiple graphs that have all every single column like above. Also my csv is already separated by commas I believe. I just wrote out "data" to show a clear example of what my data looks like.

Comment: As a bit of extra clarification, I was hoping for 3 different plots, each of the temps and pressures plotted vs time. I'm sorry if I didn't make that clear earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds this in the future, I figured out my own problem!

The problem was an error was thrown every time and all it said was

```
KeyError: 'Time'
```

This issue arose because 'Time' was my x axis and then it became my y axis through the iteration of "data". Thus is would stop every single time on the first loop.

To fix this, all I had to do was add a statement that skipped the column which was my x-axis

```
import pandas
data=pandas.read_csv(r'data.csv') 
for header in data:
    if header!="Time":
        data.plot(x='Time',y=header,legend=False)
```

This skipped the first column and allowed the rest of the headers to be plotted in separate graphs.

If headers confuses you (like it confused me at first), you can use a more general form

```
import pandas
data=pandas.read_csv(r'data.csv')
for i in list(data):
    if i!="Time":
        data.plot(x='Time',y=i,legend=False)
```

Good luck everyone!